# Hiding tab request new password

Tags: users

I want to remove the option of request new password from admin section. I have Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 *Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */

function YOURMODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  unset($form['account']['pass']);
}
```

Hope it works.